# Ternary operator for strings - any nicer way?

Tags: java, syntax, styles

I'm concerned about this construct:

```
String out = "Text " + (obj==null ? "" : obj.getStr()+" ") + "text continues.";
```

It works and all, but I think it's ugly. Maybe I'm just too picky..

Anyway, I'm asking, is there some nicer way to do this kind of stuff?
Or is this the generally accepted technique?

Comment: While I agree with fge's answer, this question might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: right, shall I delete it? I just wanted to find out some opinions..

Comment: Better to close rather than delete, but that's my personal opinion, others may disagree.

Comment: @MightyPork don't think its possible to delete now that you have answers

Comment: I could as well move it to codereview, but I'm afraid only mods can do that.. well, they can do that if they come across it, after all. Feel free to flag, there's one for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `StringBuilder`:

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Text ");
if (obj != null)
    sb.append(obj.getStr()).append(' ');
final String out = sb.append("text continues.").toString();
```

Also, why `.getStr()`? Doesn't `obj` implement `.toString()`?

---

Note that if `obj` did implement `.toString()`, you could do "better" than that using Guava's Joiner:

```
private static final Joiner JOINER = Joiner.on(" ").skipNulls();

//

final String out = JOINER.join("Text", obj, "text continues.");
```

Ultimately, though, that is a question of style.

Comment: StringBuilder would be used by compiler anyway, I think. But do you think this is _more elegant_?

Comment: `StringBuilder` is recommended while constructing strings.

Comment: Well, a ternary operator inside a `String` concatenation is... Well... Hard to read imho ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well you can separate out the logic from the format, to start with:

```
String out = String.format("Text %stextcontinues",
                           obj == null ? "" : obj.getStr() + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I like it better because it is concise.

The other way is the plain old if-then-else:

```
String toAdd = "";
if(object != null) {
    obj.getStr() + " ";
}
String out = "Text " + toAdd  + "text continues.";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String out = "Text text continues.";
if (obj != null)
   out = "Text " + obj.getStr() + " text continues.";
```